# MRL RingCT research in the Ledger Journal

Tags: ringct, monero-research-lab, research, ledger-journal

I understand that [Ledger](http://www.ledgerjournal.org/ojs/index.php/ledger):

> is a peer-reviewed scholarly journal that publishes full-length original research articles on the subjects of cryptocurrency and blockchain technology, as well as any relevant intersections with mathematics, computer science, engineering, law, and economics.  It is published online by the University Library System, University of Pittsburgh.

What are the background and qualifications of those assigned to do the peer review? Do we know the identity of "reviewer A" and "reviewer C" that are cited in the [open review](http://www.ledgerjournal.org/ojs/index.php/ledger/article/view/34/45)?

How many readers does the Journal have?

Who was behind the decision to include [Ring Confidential Transactions](http://www.ledgerjournal.org/ojs/index.php/ledger/article/view/34) by
Shen Noether, Adam Mackenzie, of the Monero Research Lab as the first [scholarly article](http://www.ledgerjournal.org/ojs/index.php/ledger/article/view/34/61) in the first issue of the journal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the background and qualifications of those assigned to do the peer review? Do we know the identity of "reviewer A" and "reviewer C" that are cited in the open review?

As with most academic journals, the reviewers are selected by the editor(s) of the journal. Reviewers are chosen based on their qualifications as they relate to the content of the article. (For instance, you wouldn't ask a cattle farmer researcher to review an article about cryptography).

As is common in academic peer review, reviewers identities are not revealed to either the authors of the article or the readers. Ledger is actually at the forefront of publication rigor by providing open reviews.

> How many readers does the Journal have?

According to the web page, the article has been viewed 1386 times at the time I'm writing this response.

> Who was behind the decision to include Ring Confidential Transactions by Shen Noether, Adam Mackenzie, of the Monero Research Lab as the first scholarly article in the first issue of the journal?

The editor(s) of the journal. So someone in this list: http://www.ledgerjournal.org/ojs/index.php/ledger/about/editorialTeam